# How I missed seeing the help link for Markdown formatting when asking a question

Tags: support, help, editing-help

*Note:
*I edited the title to more accurately match the final disposition of this question. Still leaving it around for any others who might be as clueless as I was. It's a big world. There is a non-zero probability that this could happen.*

*It turns out I was even more clueless than I originally thought I was when I asked this question. Turns out the link I was looking for **does** appear but only **after** one uses a Question's text box.*

*But this explains why I only saw the [formatting help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) link when I edited and not when I merely opened the question page. When I edited there was already text in that field. But when I just opened the new question page no text is present. Hence no formatting help link on the right.*

*Oh, well. At least I learned about the `?` help button which I honestly had never noticed before.*

*Don't I feel foolish.*

---

Recently I have started to ask a question (on Stack Overflow) and wanted to format text a certain way but could not remember how.

So I looked around for the link to "[formatting help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)" which I know I have seen somewhere before on these sites, but I cannot find it.

So I then thrash around trying to search for this help information, but I am still not clever enough to find it.

Finally I remember I saw this link when I ***editted*** a post to an existing question, not *started* a new one. So I find an old question, pretend to edit it, and *finally* I can see and follow the link to the editing-help.

So is this just me? Am I the only one who looks for the editing help when Asking a Question but cannot find it?

Perhaps there actually **is** a link to the editing help available on the "Ask Question" page and I'm just failing to notice it?

If not, I suggest that it would be a "good thing" to also make this help information more readily available to someone who is asking a question.

Comment: It's marked with one of them there `?` icons. Do you have a better suggestion to make it easier to find?

Comment: Well, the way which worked for me was to follow a link named "formatting help" which appears on the right-hand-side of the page when one clickes on "Edit" for an existing question or answer.
I don't know if this is better, but it was more "obvious" to me. The main problem I have with the ? icon is that I just completely overlooked it. I guess I would like to see the link to "Formatting Help" added to the "Ask Question" page in addition to the ? icon.

Comment: You are not alone. This should be more intuitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Stack Overflow]
[image: Programmers]
[image: Code Review]

Comment: OK, just me then. But obviously I never noticed it. IMO it doesn't really jump up and lick your face. Oh, well. Thanks for helping me to see the "obvious".

Comment: @irrational John, no it is not just you. This is non-obvious and ought to be more intuitive.

Answer (score 10):

There is a link:

[image: markdown help link - the ?]

When you click the `?` you get an edit bar and another link:

[image: toolbar and links!]